# Cargo run doesn't read json input

Tags: debugging, rust, rustrover

I'm new in rust and i have some problems.I have a project written in rust, I need to run a debug. My configuration is(rustrover):[image]

But when I run or debug, an error appears:

> Error reading args.json: Error { kind: InvalidData, message: "stream did not contain valid UTF-8" }

JSON contains the arguments to run the program.

ftp.json:

```
{
  "client": "../tests/targets/LightFTP/Source/Release/fftp",
  "client_args": ["../tests/targets/LightFTP/fftp.conf"],
  "client_envs": {"QEMU_STRACE": "1"},
  "client_files": [],
  "server": "/usr/bin/ftp",
  "server_args": ["127.0.0.1", "2200"],
  "server_envs": {"QEMU_STRACE": "1"},
  "server_files": [],
  "run_time": 300,
  "server_only": false
}
```

The error appears in the following code lines:

```
fn main() {
    is_root();

    setup_env();

    ensure_saved_states();

    println!("cwd: {:?}", std::env::current_dir().unwrap());

    let config_path: PathBuf = std::env::args()
        .nth(1)
        .expect("No config path given")
        .into();
    let args = load_args(config_path);  ///<<<<<<<<<< Error is here

    // Paths are relative to ACTIVE_DIR
    if let Err(e) = prog::run(
        &args.client,
        &args.client_args,
        &args.client_envs,
        &args.client_files,
        &args.server,
        &args.server_args,
        &args.server_envs,
        &args.server_files,
        &Duration::from_secs(args.run_time),
        args.server_only,
    ) {
        println!("Error {:?}", e);
    };
}
```

load_args:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
fn load_args(path: PathBuf) -> RunArgs {
    match fs::read_to_string(path) {
        Ok(args_json) => match serde_json::from_str(&args_json) {
            Ok(run_args) => run_args,
            Err(e) => panic!("[!] Error parsing args.json: {:?}", e),
        },
        Err(e) => panic!("[!] Error reading args.json: {:?}", e), ///<<<<<<< error 
    }
}
```

But if I try to run the program in terminal without cargo (`./target/debug/prog config/ftp.json`), it will run

Cargo.toml is:

```
[profile.release]
lto = true
opt-level = 3
debug = true

[dependencies]
fs_extra = "1.1.0"
regex = "1.3.9"
rand = "0.7.3"
libc = "0.2.82"
json = "0.12.4"
termion = "1.5.6"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
chrono = "0.4.19"
```

rustc version is:
`rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)`

cargo version is:
`cargo 1.63.0 (fd9c4297c 2022-07-01)`

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Check the working directory of the executable, from which it tries to find config/ftp.json.